# Applying Green's function for one dimensional wave equation

Tags: wave-equation, greens-function

The Green's function of the one dimensional wave equation
$$
(\partial_t^2-\partial_z^2)\phi=0
$$
fulfills
$$
(\partial_t^2-\partial_z^2)G(z,t)=\delta(z)\delta(t)
$$
I calculated that its retarded part is given by:
$$
G_+(z,t)=\Theta(t)\Theta(t-|z|).
$$
In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Table_of_Green%27s_functions) I find a very similar expression without the first $\Theta(t)$. I think this has to do with the fact that in Wikipedia the full Green's function is given and not the retarded part, right?

I now want to apply the retarded Green's function to solve the wave equation with the source
$$
\begin{cases}
(\partial_t^2-\partial_z^2)\phi=\kappa(z,t)\\
\kappa(z,t)=e^{-i\omega t+i \omega z}\Theta_L(z)
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
\Theta_L(z)=
\begin{cases}
1&0<z<L\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The formal solution is now given by:
$$
\begin{split}
\phi(z,t)&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt'\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz'\Theta(t-t')\Theta\big(t-t'-|z-z'|\big)\kappa(z',t')\\
&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}dt'\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz'\Theta\big(t-t'-|z-z'|\big)e^{-i\omega t'+i \omega z'}\Theta_L(z')\\
&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}dt'\int\limits_{0}^{L}dz'\Theta\big(t-t'-|z-z'|\big)e^{-i\omega t'+i \omega z'}\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{L}dz'e^{i \omega z'}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t-|z-z'|}dt'e^{-i\omega t'}
\end{split}
$$
I have problems with evaluating the $t'$ integral. I get
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t-|z-z'|}dt'e^{-i\omega t'}=\frac{1}{-i\omega}\left(e^{-i\omega(t-|z-z'|)}-e^{-i\omega(-\infty)}\right)
$$
where the last term is clearly not defined!

What am I doing wrong? Is it something about the boundary conditions which I should impose?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that the equation $\int_{-\infty}^{t-|z-z'|}dt'e^{-i\omega t'}=\frac{1}{-i\omega}\left(e^{-i\omega(t-|z-z'|)}-e^{-i\omega(-\infty)}\right)$ is wrong. The integral is not defined because  $\int_{-\infty}^{t-|z-z'|}dt'|e^{-i\omega t'}|=\int_{-\infty}^{t-|z-z'|}dt'=\infty$.

Comment: Have you tried solving the driven harmonic oscillator with Green's functions? That would be an easier example to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong, rather your question is actually ill-posed. Notice that your problem does not have any boundary conditions so it can't have an unambiguous answer (what happens if you add a constant to $\phi$). If your source term cut off at some point in the past, say $\kappa(z, t) = e^{- i \omega t + i \omega z} \Theta_L(z) \Theta(t - t_0)$ then your integral would look like,
$$ \int_{t_0}^{t - |z - z'|} \mathrm{d}t' e^{- i \omega t'} = \frac{i}{\omega} \left( e^{- i \omega (t - |z - z'|)} - e^{- i \omega t_0} \right) $$
which is perfectly well behaved. This corresponds to implicitly imposing boundary conditions $\phi(z, t) = 0$ in the past for $t 
\le t_0$ (I encourage you to think about how boundary contitions are incorporated into the general solution throught the Green's function). However, in your case you are taking $t_0 \to - \infty$ but we can't impose this sort of boundary condition at $- \infty$ since $\phi(z, -\infty) = 0$ isn't meaningful! This correspond to the fact that, for the solutions $\phi_{t_0}$ computed for a cutoff set at $t_0$, the limit $\lim\limits_{t_0 \to - \infty} \phi_{t_0}(z, t)$ does not exist. This is exactly the same ill-defined limit that you noticed when you couldn't compute the limit in the improper integral,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{t - |z - z'|} \mathrm{d}t' e^{- i \omega t'} = \lim_{t_0 \to - \infty}  \int_{t_0}^{t - |z - z'|} \mathrm{d}t' e^{- i \omega t'} = \lim_{t_0 \to - \infty} \frac{i}{\omega} \left( e^{- i \omega (t - |z - z'|)} - e^{- i \omega t_0} \right) $$
Now what would make your problem well-posed while retaininig the same source term $\kappa(z, t)$. Well, suppose at some $t_0$ we know the value of $\phi(z, t_0)$ and $\partial_t \phi(z, t) |_{t_0}$. Then we need to modify our Green's function $G(z,z',t,t')$ to take this information into account. Where $G$ satisfies,
$$ (\partial_t^2 - \partial_x^2) G(z, z', t, t') = \delta(t - t') \delta(x - x') $$
and the Green's function must be a function of $t$ and $t'$ (not of the form $G(z - z', t - t')$ as you had before since we require that $G(z, z', t_0, t')$ satisfy the boundary contition for all $t'$). Suppose we know $\phi(z, t_0) = 0$ and $\partial_t \phi(z, t)|_{t_0} = 0$. You will find something piecewise like,
$$ G(z, z', t, t') = 
\begin{cases}
\Theta(t - t')\Theta(t - t' - |z - z'|)  & t' > t_0
\\
\Theta(t' - t)\Theta(t' - t - |z - z'|) & t' < t_0
\end{cases}  $$
Notice the Green's function is advanced before $t_0$ and retarded afterwards conforming to the sort of causality we expect for the propagation of information about the solution at $t_0$ to information about the solution at all $t$. Now our solution takes the form,
$$ \phi(z, t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}{z'} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}{t'} G(z, z', t, t') \kappa(z', t') $$
which becomes
$$ \phi(z, t) = \int_{0}^{L} \mathrm{d}{z'}
\begin{cases}
\int_{t_0}^{t - |z - z'|} \mathrm{d}{t'} e^{- i \omega t' + i \omega z'} & t > t_0
\\
\int_{t + |z - z'|}^{t_0} \mathrm{d}{t'} e^{- i \omega t' + i \omega z'} & t < t_0
\end{cases}
\quad =
\frac{i}{\omega} \int_{0}^{L} \mathrm{d}{z'} e^{i \omega z'}
\begin{cases}
\Theta(t - t_0 - |z - z'|)\left( e^{- i \omega (t - |z - z'|)} - e^{- i \omega t_0} \right) & t > t_0
\\
\Theta(t_0 - t - |z - z'|)\left(-e^{- i \omega (t + |z - z'|)} + e^{- i \omega t_0} \right)  & t < t_0
\end{cases} $$
and thus,
$$ \phi(z, t) = \frac{i}{\omega} \mathrm{sign}(t - t_0) \left( \int_{0}^{L} \mathrm{d}{z'} \Theta(|t - t_0| - |z - z'|) \left( e^{i \omega z'} e^{\mathrm{sign}(t - t_0) i \omega | z - z'|} e^{- i \omega t} - e^{- i \omega t_0} \right)  \right) 
$$
If we replace our source with a delta function at the origin $\kappa(z, t) = e^{- i \omega t} \delta(z)$ it is easier to see what is going on. In this case we get,
$$ \phi(z, t) = \frac{i}{\omega} \mathrm{sign}(t - t_0) \Theta(|t - t_0| - |z|)  \left( e^{\mathrm{sign}(t - t_0) i \omega | z |} e^{- i \omega t} - e^{- i \omega t_0} \right)   $$
which after $t_0$ is a solution with outgoing waves from the origin and before $t_0$ is a solution with incoming waves exactly absorbed at the origin such that at $t = t_0$ all the waves cancel.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for this detailed answer! I was actually wondering if one can also impose scattering boundary conditions? I think this is for example done in the three dimensional case... Physically the source $\kappa$ describes a region between $0$ and $L$ where new particles are produced and which then exit to the left and right. The $e^{...}$ in $\kappa$ describes the incoming particles. The reason why I sent $t_0\rightarrow\infty$ was because the incoming particles come in continuously. I would then expect that the outgoing particles are also going out in a continuous way...

Comment: Usually, scattering conditions are used in case of a homogeneous equation (say the wave equation with an interaction term $U(z) \phi$) because I only know how to make sense of it when "particle number" is conserved. What do you want to happen in the region $z < 0$ for example? Should there be incoming particles being absorbed by the source? Also unfortunately beware, there are some qualativite differences with how the wave equation and its Green's function behave in 1D or 2D and in 3D.

Comment: Let me be a little bit more precise on the physics behind this problem. I consider a background field which is described by $b=e^{-i\omega t+i \omega z}$, i.e. it is a wave that propagates in the positive z-direction. I have normalized the field $b$ to one. In the region $[0,L]$ the field $b$ can interact with other particles and the particle species $\phi$ can be produced. The mathematical description for the production of $\phi$ is described in the original post. What I would expect is that there are some $\phi$ produced in the forward direction $\phi_+\sim e^{-i\omega t+i\omega z}$ and(1/2)

Comment: (2/2) in the backward direction $\phi_-\sim e^{-i\omega t-i\omega z}$... However I cannot show this mathematically with the Green's function...

Comment: You are still going to need some sort of boundary conditions (else you can always add a solution to the homogeneous wave equation). You might look at how people impose scattering conditions on Green's functions there are a lot of possibilities depending on exactly how your problem arises and exactly the physics you want to model. I should mention in the "real world" interactions are often not past-eternal so having the interaction turn on at some $t_0$ is not unphysical but it does make the math a bit harder. Another thing people sometimes do in physics if you know what the answer should (1/2)

Comment: "look like" but don't know what boundary conditions to impose you can do the following sort of ad hoc tricks. Just pretend that $e^{- i \omega (- \infty)} \to 0$ and see that you get a solution that "looks right" then go back and try to modify your Green's function to actually get this solution. This will tell you what boundary conditions you would need to impose in order to get the solution that "looks right". I as said, there are many solutions to this differential equation, you need to specify which one you want. The Green's function can't know unless you tell it!